# My stored procedure randomly fails due to invalid object in a swapping database instance

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a stored procedure in my database (say it is CustomerDB) which joins with a table function in a different database (say it is dbPerformance), the sp is something like:

```
select something from CustomerDB.dbo.CustoemrData left join 
                dbPerformance.dbo.FnPerformanceDayEnd(CustoemrData.Code, 1,1)
```

The dbPerformance database contains quite a lot of data and to update the data, DBA actually first populate the new data into a db called dbPerformanceNew, when the new database is ready, it will restore the dbPerformance database from dbPerformanceNew.

Randomly I saw error from such as Invalid object name 'dbPerformance.dbo.FnPerformanceDayEnd' from my sp. The timing does related to the time that the old database dbPerformance was being restored from dbPerformanceNew.

My confusion is that when the restore happens, it already has all the data and all the functions. I thought at least I should see error like dbPerformance database is unavailable (as the dbPerformanceNew database is being restored), other than some objects are not available.

Anyone got some experiences?

Comment: your best bet is to ask on dba. my **wild** guess (you didn't specify how the restore is performed): a `SELECT...INTO` is run after a massive `DROP` hence the error.

Comment: DBA's guess was that somehow sql server is confused (as we were switching from one db to another) and the query somehow stuck to the old database. But we can't explain the error message at all at the moment

Comment: well you can post on dba.stackexchange.com with some more detail about the issue; there you will likely find more people experienced on sql.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be caused by actions done by DBA. Not a programming question.